# How to deal with map fragment button?

Tags: android, google-maps, button, android-activity, fragment

I have button at my map fragment in tab activity as shown in picture but I have no idea where to implement onClickListener of this button and other Map functions of onLocationChanged ,onConnectionSuspened etc please help !!

**Edited** **Add Code**

**MapsActivity.Java**

```
public class MapsActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
    AsyncResponse, View.OnClickListener,
    OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i("okkk", " ho jamaaloooo ");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    newString = intent.getLongExtra("user_id", newString);
    btn_rest = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_rest);
    btn_rest.setOnClickListener(this);
}
 @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // getPars
    Log.i("okk",  "Click ");

    HashMap postData = new HashMap();
    PostResponseAsyncTask task = new PostResponseAsyncTask(this, postData);
    task.execute("http://ashna.netau.net/A_location.php");
}
```

**TabACtivity.java**
call map fragment from here

```
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Log.i("okkk", "Position: " + position);
        try {
            switch (position) {
                case 0: {
                    return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
                }
                case 1: {
                    Deals deals = new Deals();
                    return deals;
                }
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception e)
        {
            Log.i("okkk", "Exception 1 : " + e);
        }
        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }
```

**MapActivity.xml**

```
 <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/map"
tools:context=".MapsActivity"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
tools:layout="@layout/abc_action_menu_layout"/>

<Button

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Nearby Resturants"
    android:id="@+id/btn_rest"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
```

[image]

Comment: Which button ? are you talking about floating Actin button at the right corner with message icon?

Comment: No Button at the top (Nearby Resturant) @tahsinRupam

Comment: you can implement in oncreate.

Comment: its not working :|  @AAA it only shows button

Comment: @android it should work. if dont then please show code

Comment: @AAA Please check my code

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this code below, hope it help but it is better if you can provide your code.

```
public class MapFragment extends BaseFragment implements LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private Location mCurrentLocation;
private MapView mMapView;
private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private String provider;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, null);

    mMapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Button nearBy = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.nearby_button);
    nearBy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        // DO SOMETHING FOR NEARBY BUTTOM
    }

    return view;

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    mMapView.onResume();
    super.onResume();

    initMap();

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mMapView.onPause();

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mMapView.onDestroy();
}

private void initMap() {
    Log.d("MapFragment", "init map");

    mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mGoogleMap = googleMap;
            mGoogleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new PopupAdapter(mContext, getLayoutInflater(null)));
            mGoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                    marker.showInfoWindow();
                    return true;
                }
            });
            MapsInitializer.initialize(mContext);
        }
    });

}

private void locateMyLocation(Location currentLocation) {
    mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.map_user_location_title))
            .anchor(0.0f, 1.0f)
            .position(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude())));
    mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude()), 15.0f));
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mCurrentLocation = location;

    locateMyLocation(mCurrentLocation);

    //stop location updates
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    Log.d("MapFragment", "buildGoogleApiClient");

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

}

Comment: I called map fragment from tab activity , so it only display only button not doing any on onClickListener